# Using regex to split text content into dictionary

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dictionary, split

I have a text file that follows this format.

> LESTER HOLT (00:00:01): Breaking News Tonight: A deadly mass shooting
>   at the airport. A gunman opens fire at baggage claim in Fort
>   Lauderdale, witnesses describing scenes of sheer horror. A silent
>   killer shooting people in the head as they tried to run and hide.
>   Tonight, a storm of questions. Why did he do it? The suspect, a
>   passenger with a firearm in his checked bag. New concerns about
>   airport security before the checkpoint.
>
> (00:00:25): Also breaking tonight the new report from U.S.
>   intelligence: Vladimir Putin himself ordered the effort to influence
>   the election, aimed at hurting Clinton and helping Trump win. What the
>   President-elect is saying after his top-secret briefing.
>
> (00:00:39): And States of Emergency: Millions from coast to coast
>   paralyzed by a massive winter storm.
>
> (00:00:45): NIGHTLY NEWS begins right now.

I am trying to parse this information into a Python Dictionary, where the speaker is a dictionary, of dictionaries, which has timecode keys, and the content is the value, I can't consistently split because of potential information before the timecode, (IE the first quote), as well as the fact that the split character `:` is also a character involved with the timecode itself `00:00:00`.

Trying to split according to the regex.

```
for line in msg.get_payload().split('\n'):
    regex = r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
    test = re.split(regex, line)
    print(test)
    sleep(1)
```

Appears to work in splitting it properly, but it causes me to lose the value I am splitting on (timecode), which I intend to use as a key. How can I properly split the above content, get the speaker, and then get the timecode as a key, and the content as a value.It is possible he may be present later in the text as well, and it should append to the list of timecodes./

The output format I am targeting is something along the lines of

```
{speakers:{'Lester Holt': {'00:00:01':content..., '00:00:0025': content...},
'speaker2':{etc,etc,etc} }}
```

Ive tried using the split as mentioned above, but it removes my timecode variable.

Any thoughts and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Before trying a regex solution, could you just split on `):`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you're killing the regex fun :)

Comment: Maybe something like `([\w\s]*?)(\(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\)):(.*)(?:\n\n|$)` [DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/UZAnmW/2)

Comment: I could, yes, but without being 100% sure that that ): does not exist in all txt files that may or may not include that in the content

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see what you are saying, I just need to expand the regex further to surround the tiemstamp as well. Thank you

Comment: @Busturdust if you're not familiar with them already, I suggest looking up "capturing groups", which is a way of extracting text from text that matches the regex.

Comment: Thank you, I will do so. It seems I was stuck in my old "string split" mechanisms -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with `split`. You're trying to get 2-3 pieces of information out of each line, so try the following:

```
for line in msg.get_payload().split('\n'):
    match = re.search(r'^\s*([^(]*?)\s*\((\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\):\s*(.*)$', line)
    if match:
        (speaker, time, message) = match.groups()
```

Speaker will be an empty string if none was present on that line.

Regex explanation:

```
^                    # Start of line
\s*                  # Drop leading whitespace
([^(]*?)             # Capture the speaker if present (non-paren characters)
\s*                  # Drop whitespace between name and time
\(                   # Drop literal open paren
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})  # Capture time
\):\s*               # Drop literal close paren, colon and whitespace
(.*)                 # Capture the rest of the line
$                    # End of line
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I am new to regex, I am going to review the expression and test it out. However on a first run, it looks like it worked pretty cleanly. Thank you for your quick effort

Comment: and then he updates it with the explanations, wonderful thank you!

Comment: Is there some tool you're using to generate the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Splitting message in lines when you need to split it in time-stamped paragraphs is a waste. `re.split` can easily save the tokens that it split on, if you only look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Here's my solution:

```
toks = re.split(r"\((\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\):", msg.get_payload())[1:]
answer = dict(zip(toks[::2], toks[1::2]))
```

This creates a dictionary of timestamps and paragraphs. Feel free to use the same approach to split by speaker as well.

Result:
    {
        '00:00:01': ' Breaking News Tonight: A .....',
        '00:00:25': ' Also breaking tonight ......', ....
    }

Comment: This is pretty neat, allow me some time to review